# Make floated div displayed as table inherit heigh

Tags: html, css

What i'm trying to do is to have 2 floated divs, One is image only, and another is all kinds of content.
Content in content div needs to be vertically centered, and its height needs to be equal to the height of image div.
So, i've run into problem  where div displayed as table would not inherit height because of being floated. What can i do in this situation?

Here is the code. Most of its relevant styles can be seen in classes. 
The only thing that's not in styles is
**Eidt:** added styles per request. Rest of the styles is bg, fonts, etc..

```
.txtimgcont {width:49.5%;}
.txtimgwrap {width:100%;}
.table {display:table;}
.tablecell {display:table-cell;}
.floatright {float:right;}
.middle {vertical-align:middle;}
```

html

```
<div class="txtimgwrap txtimgwrap1 clearfix">

  <div class="txtimgcont table floatright">
    <div class="tablecell middle w100"> 
      <div>content</div>
      <div>content</div>
      <div>content</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="txtimgcont txtimgimgcont floatright">
    <img class="imgheightread" src="http://" />
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Can you post the CSS rules for the classes?

Comment: Wrap your image div inside the wrapper div -> http://jsfiddle.net/qbt72a96/